# PostgreSQL , SQL: Starting script with two scenarios

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to write a query that starts according to two scenarios.
For example, I have a table like this:

```
create table test_table (
    id INT,
    gender INT,
    counry VARCHAR(50),
    amount INT
);
insert into test_table (id, gender, country, amount) values (1, 1, 'Australia', 329);
insert into test_table (id, gender, country, amount) values (2, 0, 'Thailand', 293);
insert into test_table (id, gender, country, amount) values (3, 1, 'China', 146);
insert into test_table (id, gender, country, amount) values (4, 1, 'Sweden', 497);
insert into test_table (id, gender, country, amount) values (5, 0, 'China', 161);
insert into test_table (id, gender, country, amount) values (6, 0, 'Russia', 237);
insert into test_table (id, gender, country, amount) values (7, 1, 'China', 300);
insert into test_table (id, gender, country, amount) values (8, 0, 'China', 488);
```

Table:

```
id  gender  country    amount
1   1      Australia    329
2   0      Thailand     293
3   1      China        146
4   1      Sweden       497
5   0      China        161
6   0      Russia       237
7   1      China        300
8   0      China       488
```

I need to get two different query results by checking first:

```
select 
case when id=3 and gender =0 then (select id, country, amount*2 from public.test_table)
when id=3 and gender =1 then (select id, amount*5 from public.test_table) end
from public.test_table
```

This way is bad and can only return a single column..

That is, I need to check first which gender belongs to the specific user and accordingly return different queries.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not following. According to your data for a given `id` there is only going to be one `gender` so I'm not seeing a need for two queries.

Comment: Yes, one id to one gender, so when I query I want to check what is gender for this id. And according to the result to get different queries.

Comment: This is a classic *[XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)*. Please describe the problem you are attempting to solve (not how to solve it). That would be a description of the problem without reference to SQL.

Comment: I need to get a table according to two different queries that run according to preconditions.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
SELECT 
    id, gender, country, 
    CASE WHEN gender = 0 THEN  
            amount * 2 
         ELSE 
            amount * 5 
         END AS amount  
FROM 
    test_table 
WHERE 
    id = 3;

 id | gender | country | amount 
----+--------+---------+--------
  3 |      1 | China   |    730


SELECT 
    id, gender, country, 
    CASE WHEN gender = 0 THEN  
            amount * 2 
         ELSE 
            amount * 5 
         END AS amount  
FROM 
    test_table 
WHERE 
    id = 8;
 id | gender | country | amount 
----+--------+---------+--------
  8 |      0 | China   |    976
```

The `amount` portion is the only part that needs modifying, so just put it in the `CASE` .

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
But the result should be different queries:
if id=3 and gender=0 the result query id, country, amount*2
if id=3 and gender= 1 id, amount*5
first result  3 columns
the second result  only 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `case` expression to calculate the final amount:

```
select id, gender, country,
       (case when gender = 0 then amount * 2 else amount * 5 end) as new_amount
from public.test_table;
```

You can add a `where` if you only want a particular user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
But the result should be different queries:
if id=3 and gender=0 the result query id, country, amount*2
if id=3 and gender= 1 id, amount*5
first result  3 columns
the second result  only 2 columns